# Number format column type & calculate in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, numbers

1. I would like to insert this type of number format in to my database.

   ```
   $value = "20.000,00";
   ```

   I tried with `FLOAT` and `DOUBLE`, but they can't handle this. Only option left that I know which works is `VARCHAR`?
2. Although if I do this when I am working with the numbers later and tries to subtract number from each other:

   ```
   $value2 = "15.933,50";
   $calc = $value - $value2;
   ```

   `$calc` is now `4.067`, it should be `4.066,50` - how can this be correct?

Comment: What method of number system is that?

Comment: @GiantofaLannister Swedish number format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For financial numbers, you should use [the DECIMAL type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fixed-point-types.html). It has a fixed precision and isn't subject to the rounding problems of floating point numbers.

Never store a money number in a VARCHAR or a FLOAT.

If you want to introduce in the database your `$value`, you must parse it so that you can introduce the number :

```
$fmt = new NumberFormatter( 'da_DK', NumberFormatter::DECIMAL );
$num = $fmt->parse($value, NumberFormatter::TYPE_INT32)
```

To display a number you got from your DB as "20.000,00", you may use

```
$display_value = $fmt->format($num);
```

**EDIT :**

If you can't use a NumberFormatter, you may use this to build a string that you can introduce in a DECIMAL field (in a float one too but don't) :

```
$v = str_replace(',', '.', str_replace('.', '', $value));
```

This changes `"20.000,00"` to `"20000.00"` which the database can understand.
But it's always dangerous to ask a database to parse the strings as numbers (you may change the locale later). I'd recommend you to parse the number in PHP and to explicitly specify the locale.

Comment: I'm afraid I dont have the NumberFormatter class.  How can I convert this: 2.000,50 into 2000.50 (inserting to db)

Comment: You may use str_replace to replace the '.' by nothing and the ',' by a point (see edit).